# Cannot open TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift5

While working on some IOS project (Swift5) which includes login functionality, I encountered strange problem which is to open on button click a new UITableViewController which includes some records from database. Strange because this same functionality works without any problem from the login view and doesn't work from the view once the user gets logged in.

This is the method which opens new Controller:

```
 @IBAction func didTapButton(sender: Any) {
    
   // let story : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",        
   bundle:nil)
    
    let categories = CategoriesTableViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(categories, 
    animated: true)
    

    //        let controller =  
    story.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
    "CategoriesTableViewController") as! 
    CategoriesTableViewController
    //
    //        present(controller, animated: true)
    
    }
```

And this is an error which occurs while I run this above method  on click once I am logged into this application:

```
Exception   NSException *   "-  
[project7_4_adm.ViewController       
didTapButtonWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent 
to instance 0x7f9889222260" 0x0000600001d35860
```

I found in google some solution which is to add target to the button which I did:

```
   btn.addTarget(self, action: 
   #selector(didTapButton(sender:)), for: 
   .touchUpInside)
```

but even though I did that I got an error:

```
    Thread 1: "-
    [project7_4_adm.CategoriesTableViewController  
    initWithIdentifier:source:destination:]: unrecognized 
    selector sent to instance 0x7fac3a11df90"
```

Could I ask you to write to me what can be a reason of this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Your target selector is defined as having one parameter (sender).  Your implementation has none.

Comment: @ Phillip Mills it's got the parameter, just edited and added.

Answer (score 0):

The exception reason clearly states that `didTapButton(sender...` is *translated* to Objective-C as `didTapButtonWithSender:`

In an `IBAction` you have to insert an underscore character

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any)
```

and a selector can be simply

```
#selector(didTapButton)
```

Comment: this method includes this parameter, I updated the above.

Comment: An `IBAction` must include the parameter and the underscore character hides only the **external** parameter name.

Comment: it's got the parameter and underscore and I have still got the error

Comment: In Interface Builder reconnect the action.